# parameter tuning using nested cross validation

Tags: svm, cross-validation, parameterization

Parameter tuning in SVM has been performed using a nested cross-validation(CV) approach with 45 folds(outer loop) and 13 folds(inner loop). In this process, the outer loop will have 45 prediction tasks with a chosen best value for C from the inner loop. I have taken the values 0.5, 5, 50, 500 for tuning the parameter C and observed that F1-score was highest 34 times for value 5, 6 times for value 50, 5 times for value 500.

Would it be a good idea to test the model on an external dataset(not involved in nested CV) with value 5 for C(highest frequent best value) ?

Answer (score 1):

Getting a **final performance estimate** for the best model parameters found with cross validation (CV) on new data is a good idea. As you suggest, this should be be done using a dataset left out during CV that is yet *unseen* by the model.

Having said this, you could combine your inner and outer CV for doing *model tuning* and *model selection* at the same time, e.g. using **repeated cross validation**. For example, if you used 10 partitions with 20 repeats (including re-partitioning), this would leave you with 200 CV performance estimates per model type and parameter set to evaluate, from which you could decide upon the best suited model type and parametrization *at the same time*. Have a look at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213571/l2-regularized-mlr-using-caret-and-how-to-make-sure-i-am-using-the-best-tuned-mo/213662#213662) for some more details and an example on how to do this with e.g. R caret.

PS: as you are only tuning `C` I'm assuming you are using a linear kernel?

**Edit**: [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65156/112731) on a related question dealing with nested cross validation has excellent information on how to use repeated cross validation for model tuning and model selection and what its benefits are.